# awk - condition find line by regex / string and delete last line

Tags: regex, awk, find, conditional-statements, skip

I got a convoluted transaction csv. I need to extract data that begins at a certain line / field containing a string "Transaktion" and also to skip the last line of (each) csv.

I can make AWK find the starting line and process then all following. That is fine, but I can't add a way to skip last line.

```
/^Transaktionen/,/^$/ {
getline; 
print $2 FS $3 FS $4}
```

Comment: Please post example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^Transaktionen/{p=1; next} p {
   if (c2 != "") print c2, c3, c4; c2=$2; c3=$3; c4=$4}' file.csv
```

Try this awk script:

```
BEGIN {
        #OFS=FS=";" ;
        #print $0;
        print "Datum2;Zahlart3;TXN Kundendetails4 - KundenID5;Beschreibung6;Betrag7;Gebuehr10;Disagio11;Auszahlungsbetrag12";
        #einnahmen = "Transaktionen";
        #erstattung = "Refunds";
}
/^Transaktionen/{p=1; next} p {
   if (c2 != "")
      print c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 , c7 ,c10, c11, c12;
   c2=$2; c3=$3; c4=$4; c5=$5; c6=$6; c7=$7; c10=$10; c11=$11; c12=$12;
}
```

Comment: Your updated script did run through and works! Splendid and many thanks! I had to add a OFS=FS=";"  for my input and all is fine for now.